How to extract part of the string using sed?
I have already found simillair case check
In my case, have a name of file: backup_20240827000025.sql, I need to extract characters with sed - 20240827
For this string, I'm trying to execute sed with regex in centos7 sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.
string=backup_20240827000025.sql
echo $string | sed -r  's/\.\/[a-z]{6}\w\([0-9]{8}\)[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/p'
Error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 49: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

If I remove \ backslashes that surround the parentheses
\.\/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3},

then I receive my string back as it was:
./backup_20240827000025.sql


However, if I use python and this regex
'\.\/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}' 

it works well and give an output like 20240827.
Can anyone help with this ? Thanks.

If the leading backup_ is constant you don't need sed. Try echo "${string:7:8}".

The string does not begin with ./, yet your pattern seems to expect a leading ./.  Also, string contains a _ after the word backup, and your pattern does not seem to account for that.  Since the pattern will not match at all, the attempt to use \1 fails.

Your input string doesn't begin with ./ so your regex does not match at all. Similarly, \* matches a literal asterisk, but there are none in your input string.
It's not clear why you double the asterisks and other quantifiers; these are syntax errors.
\w is not portable, though it's probably supported on CentOS.
With a simple, well-formed regex, you get
bash$ echo "backup_20240827000025.sql" |
> sed -r -n 's/[a-z]{6}[^a-z0-9]*([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/p'
20240827


It was my misprint. So original string is:
./backup_20240822000015.sql
Asterisks were added Casually.
Original regex was ./[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+.[a-z]{3}
But I have tried replace \w with _ or . but anyway, with no results.

This answer makes less sense after you changed your question, but rolling back your changes seems moot now. Going forward, please don't change your questions in such a way as to render answers invalid.

Can you try a simpler regular expression?
$ string=backup_20240827000025.sql
$ echo "$string" | sed -r 's/backup_([0-9]{8}).*/\1/'
20240827


thank you for your help, I have checked and it works, but what is the reason of my error? All looks good. I just trying to understand.

Addressing OP's error ...
Without the -r option you must indicate to sed when parens are to be used to designate a capture group. You do this be escaping the parens that enclose the capture group, eg:
$ x=abcdef

$ sed 's/.*\(cd\).*/XX\1XX/' <<< "${x}"
XXcdXX

If you use the -r option then you no longer need to escape the parens (ie, the parens are treated as special characters), eg:
$ sed -r 's/.*(cd).*/XX\1XX/' <<< "${x}"
XXcdXX

In fact, if you use the -r option then you must not escape the parens that enclose the capture group.  When you escape the parens you are telling sed that these are literal parens (ie, do not treat them as special characters).  In OP's case the combination of -r and escaped parens leaves the sed command with no capture groups which in turn means the \1 designation refers to a non-existent/invalid reference:
$ sed -r 's/.*\(cd\).*/XX\1XX/' <<< "${x}"
      ^^      ^^  ^^     ^^
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

So OP's sed call should look like:
sed -r 's/\.\/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/p'
                        ^        ^ ---- parents are not escaped

But now OP runs into other issues ...
\.\/[a-z]{6} says we're looking for a string that consist of the literals . (period) + / (fwd slash) + [a-z]{6} (6 lowercase characters).  But OP's sample data does not include the literal characters . + / so we see no changes:
$ echo "$string" | sed -r 's/\.\/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/p'
backup_20240827000025.sql

Our first attempt at addressing this latest issue is to remove the \.\/ but then we run into a new issue:
$ echo "$string" | sed -r 's/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/p'
20240827
20240827

Double output?
By default sed will automatically print the pattern space (the 1st 20240827) while the /p operation says to explicitly print the pattern space, again (the 2nd 20240827).
To limit output to just one copy of the pattern space we have a couple options:
######
# add '-n' to suppress automatic printing of the pattern space

echo "$string" | sed -r -n 's/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/p'
                        ^^
######
# or remove the 'p' operation

echo "$string" | sed -r 's/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/'

Both of these will generate the single pattern space:
20240827


One performance related item to keep in mind ...
When piping output of one command to a second command the shell will spawn a subprocess for the second command.  Spawning a subprocess is relatively expensive in terms of resources and time and becomes quite noticeable when spawning an excessive number of subshells.
While OP's generation of a singl subshell won't be noticeable at the command prompt, it is good practice to get into the habit of eliminating unnecessary subshells when possible.
This may consist of re-arranging the current command or even using different features of the shell.
One idea would see us eliminate the unnecessary echo in favor of a here string:
$ sed -r 's/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/' <<< "$string"
20240827                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Alternatively, since OP appears to be working with fixed length strings we can make use of bash's substring feature ("${var:start:length}"):
$ echo "${string:7:8}"

NOTE: the 1st character is in position 0
If we're dealing with a variable number of characters before the _  we can make use of parameter substitution:
$ dt="${string#*_}"                     # strip off leading <string1>_
$ typeset -p dt
declare -- dt="20240827000025.sql"

$ echo "${dt:0:8}"                      # now use the substring feature
20240827

In OP's example we merely want to print the substring to stdout.  If OP needs to capture the substring into a variable then we have another performance issue ...
The following will also spawn a subshell ($( command ... )):
$ newvar=$( sed -r 's/[a-z]{6}\w([0-9]{8})[0-9]+\.[a-z]{3}/\1/' <<< "$string" )
$ typeset -p newvar
declare -- newvar="20240827"

The good news is that we can re-use the parameter substitution and substring solutions to eliminate this additional subshell
$ newvar="${string:7:8}"
$ typeset -p newvar
declare -- newvar="20240827"

$ dt="${string#*_}" 
$ newvar="${dt:0:8}"
$ typeset -p newvar
declare -- newvar="20240827"

